# html table colspan rowspan Piet Mondrian

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I am trying to build an html-table-like-version of [Piet Mondrian's famous photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liBzn.jpg):

[image: An image of Piet Mondrian's artwork 'Composition in Red, Blue and White.']

I've succeeded (I think) with the `rowspan` and `colspan` stuff, but the width and height seems to be not quite as the original photo.

Here is what I've done:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    <style>
      td
      {
        border:solid 1px black;
        width:20px;
        height:20px;
      }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table>
      <tr id="tr0">
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="3"></td>
        <td colspan="6"rowspan="6"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr1">
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr2">
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr3">
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="3"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr4">
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr5">
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr6">
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"></td>
        <td colspan="5" rowspan="2"></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr7">
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do not use tables for layout. Use them for presenting data..

Comment: I know this, but this was just a play for me, i wish it worked...

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem was that it fits the size by its content, so I added a a hidden column in each row and a hidden row with 8 columns, so that the table fits its size by the number of columns I needed. Now I have a different problem with a line that sits there and I don't know why...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    <style>
      td
      {
        border:solid 3px black;
        width:20px;
        height:20px;
      }
      .nob
      {
        border:0px;
      }
      table
      {
        border-collapse:collapse;
      }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="nob"></td>
        <td class="nob"></td>
        <td class="nob"></td>
        <td class="nob"></td>
        <td class="nob"></td>
        <td class="nob"></td>
        <td class="nob"></td>
        <td class="nob"></td>
        <td class="nob"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr0">
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="3"></td>
        <td colspan="6"rowspan="6" style="background-color:red;"></td>
        <td class="nob"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr1">
        <td class="nob"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr2">
        <td class="nob"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr3">
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="3"></td>
        <td class="nob"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr4">
        <td class="nob"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr5">
        <td class="nob"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr6">
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"  style="background-color:blue;"></td>
        <td colspan="5" rowspan="2"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="nob"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr7">
        <td style="background-color:yellow;"></td>
        <td class="nob"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```